# How would I properly split command args into a organized array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

So, lets say you have this string:

```
alert the message 'Howdy World!'
```

How would I split that neatly into an array:

```
["alert", "the message", "Howdy World!"]
```

Also, this can work for:

`alert the message 'How are you?' to the player`

To

```
['alert', 'the message', 'How are you?', 'to the player']
```

If you can explain how I could possibly do this, that would be great.

EDIT:

"alert" is the command name,

"the command" is a string of extra words,

"'How are you?'" is important information, and

"to the player" is a string of extra words.

This could possibly be put in

```
<command> <extra> <important> <extra>
```

If there is a possible way to seperate the string

```
alert the message 'How are you?' to the player
```

to

```
['alert', 'the message', "'How are you?'", 'to the player']
```

Then that is what I am trying to find.

Comment: I find this very random, isn't there a consistent pattern ?

Comment: There is. First, the command name, alert, then extra words, the message, then the string, How are you, then the other extra words.

Comment: pass ass in string quotes `'alert' 'the message' 'Howdy World!'`

Comment: Is there a fixed number of words for command name/extra words/message/the string (e.g. commands can only be 1 word long)?

Comment: Rather than sharing examples alone, you need to share the format explicitly `<<single-word-command>> <<two words-the message>> <<3 word text>>`.

Comment: I would need it to be flexible, but I was trying to find a possible way

Comment: @LeoDog896 Even if it has to be flexible, it still needs to have a **defined pattern**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this.. say

```
var string = "'alert' 'the message' 'How are you?' 'to the player'"
var result  = string.split("''");
window.alert(result);
```